# NameError: global name 'numKilos' is not defined

Tags: python, global-variables, nameerror

```
def inputKilos():

    while True:
        numKilos = float(raw_input("Enter a number of Kilometers.  Enter 0 to end program. "))

        if numKilos == 0:
            break 
        else: 
            convert_kilos(numKilos)

    return

def convert_kilos(numKilos):
    numMiles = numKilos * 0.6214
    print_output()
    return

def print_output():
    print numKilos, "kilometers eqauls", numMiles, "miles."

def main():
    inputKilos()

main()
```

When I try to run the program it says "**NameError: global name 'numKilos' is not defined**"  I don't know why it says numKilos isn't defined.  numKilos is equal to the number that the user enters.

Answer (score 3):

`numKilos` is a local variable in both `inputKilos` and `convert_kilos`, but not `print_output`. Local variables can only be accessed from within that function.

To pass variables around, use `return <value>` to return a value from the function, then collect it by using `result = function()`, or do the reverse by passing values into functions (like you did with `convert_kilos`.

Answer (score 0):

Those are local variables not global.

You can try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def inputKilos():
    while True:
        numKilos = float(raw_input("Enter a number of Kilometers.  Enter 0 to end program. "))
        if numKilos == 0:
            break 
        else: 
            miles = convert_kilos(numKilos)
            print_output(numKilos,miles)
    return

def convert_kilos(numKilos):
    numMiles = numKilos * 0.6214
    return numMiles

def print_output(numKilos,numMiles):
    print numKilos, "kilometers eqauls", numMiles, "miles."


inputKilos()
```

Or using global keyword:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

numKilos=0
numMiles=0

def inputKilos():
    while True:
        global numKilos
        numKilos = float(raw_input("Enter a number of Kilometers.  Enter 0 to end program. "))
        if numKilos == 0:
            break 
        else: 
            convert_kilos(numKilos)
            print_output

def convert_kilos(numKilos):
    global numKilos
    global numMiles
    numMiles = numKilos * 0.6214    

def print_output:
    global numKilos
    global numMiles
    print numKilos, "kilometers eqauls", numMiles, "miles."


inputKilos()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a refactored version:

```
MILES_PER_KM = 0.621371

def get_float(prompt=''):
    while True:
        try:
            return float(raw_input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            pass

def main():
    while True:
        kms = get_float('Enter a distance in kms (or 0 to exit): ')
        if kms:
            miles = MILES_PER_KM * kms
            print '  {} kilometers is {} miles.'.format(kms, miles)
        else:
            break

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```